# vLookup Match different lookup array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

Can someone please advise the correct method to use so that I can dynamically change the `Lookup_Array` in a Match condition.

The following formula works fine;

```
=VLOOKUP(F22,A26:O2000,MATCH(A9,A26:O26,0),FALSE)
```

However based on other criteria I would like the Lookup Array to be different, instead of being `A26:026` it would be `A34:O34`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, i have worked it out for myself please see below if anyone else has the same problem

> =IF(J5>=INDEX(TCT.xls!pArray,MATCH(O5,TCT.xls!pGroup,0),5),INDEX(TCT.xls!pArray,MATCH(O5,TCT.xls!pGroup,0),5),J5)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand your question to be, you can use `Indirect()`.  Assuming that cell A1 has `A26:O26` (literally typed, in the cell).  You can use this formula,

`=VLOOKUP(F22,A26:O2000,MATCH(A9,INDIRECT(A1),0),FALSE)`

Then, if you want to use another range instead of `A26:O26`, just replace what's in cell A1.

Comment: Thanks for that , i have worked it out myself, see below;